# Too many re render Protected Route -ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, routes

I am new to react and I tried to make Protected routes which works perfectly on local but on server it gives the error.[image]

my Code is as follows

**Protected Route**

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');  
    return (
      <Route
        {...restOfProps}
        render={(props) =>
          token && userId ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
      />
    );
  }
  
  export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Main Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "../Shared/Navbar";
import List from "./ListComponent";
import Login from "./LoginComponent";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Item from "./Item";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // this.state = {
        //     token: '',
        //     userId: ''
        // }
        // this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this);
        this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
    }

    // handleData(token, userId) {
    //     this.setState({ token: token, userId: userId });
    //     localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    //     localStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
    //     window.location='/';
    // }

    handleLogout(){
        this.setState({token: ''})
        this.setState({userId:'' })
        localStorage.setItem('userId','')
        localStorage.setItem('token', '');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Router>
                    <Navbar handleLogout={this.handleLogout}/>
                    <Switch>
                        <ProtectedRoute exact path ={["/home","/"]} component={Dashboard} />
                        <ProtectedRoute exact path ="/list" component={List} />
                        <ProtectedRoute exact path ="/item" component={Item} />
                        <ProtectedRoute exact path ="/item/:id" component={Item} />
                        {/*<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>*/}
                        {
                            localStorage.getItem('token') === '' && localStorage.getItem('userId') === ''
                            ?<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                            :<Redirect to='/'/>
                        }
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Here when i comment protected Route condition it works on server but the login page is accessible.

**LoginComponent**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import api from "../../http-common";

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            // tokenData: ''
        }
        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
        this.handleUsername = this.handleUsername.bind(this);
        this.handlePassword = this.handlePassword.bind(this);
    }

    handleUsername(e){
        if(e.target.value.length > 0){
            this.setState({username: e.target.value})
        }
    }

    handlePassword(e){
        this.setState({password: e.target.value})
    }

    handleLogin(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    }
    async login(username, password) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', username);
        formData.append('password',password);
        await api.post('/api/login', formData)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200 && response.data.token !== '') {
                    // console.log(response.data)
                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                    localStorage.setItem('userId', response.data.userId);
                    window.location='/'
                    // this.setState({tokenData: response.data.token});
                    // this.props.handleData(this.state.tokenData, this.state.username);
                } else if (response.status === 200 && response.data.token === '' && response.data.message === 'User not Found') {
                    alert(response.data.message)
                } else if (response.status === 200 && response.data.token === '' && response.data.message === 'User is not valid') {
                    alert(response.data.message)
                } else {
                    console.log(response.statusText);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                            <div className="card mt-3 mx-3 px-3 py-3">
                                <div className="mx-1">
                                    <div className="form-group row">
                                        <label htmlFor="username" className="mr-2">Username</label>
                                        <div className="m-auto">
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                id="username"
                                                name="username"
                                                className="form-control mb-3"
                                                placeholder="Username"
                                                required="required"
                                                onChange={this.handleUsername}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="form-group row">
                                        <label htmlFor="password" className="mr-2">Password</label>
                                        <div className="mx-auto">
                                            <input
                                                type="password"
                                                id="password"
                                                name="password"
                                                className="form-control"
                                                placeholder="Password"
                                                required="required"
                                                onChange={this.handlePassword}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Please Help, Thank You.

Comment: which react-router-dom version you used currently ?

Comment: @ParthNavadiya "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "paginate-array": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",

Comment: No, i was asking about react-router-dom

Comment: @ParthNavadiya it is 8.1.3

Comment: i think it's nor react-router-dom version beacuse it's latest version is 6.0.x

Comment: @ParthNavadiya sorry it is 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So as per your environment and my understanding your routing go on loop so you must have to update your Main route file like below or check same in [codesendbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dirac-vb8di?file=/src/Main.js)

```
   <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path ={["/home","/"]} component={Dashboard} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path ="/list" component={List} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path ="/item" component={Item} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path ="/item/:id" component={Item} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
   </Switch>
```

I hope it will works for you now! Thanks.